SQL table with thousands of columns
I need to store data(float) from 20,000 sensors once a second. I originally wanted to create the following table：



time
sensor 1
sensor 2
...
sensor 20000




2024-09-06 13:00:00
1.2
5.3
....
2.0



But then I found a table cannot have more than 1600 columns in PostgreSQL. What's the best practice to store this kind of data? Separate them into multiple tables or switch to another type of DB?
All 20000 sensor values are read and inserted together.
I need to query up to 100 of them per second to plot trend charts.

Different rows would be the common way. However, 20000 insert/second is a lot. What dbms and hw do you have?

I suggest extracting Sensors table, then you'll have Measurements table with tiem, sensor_id, measurement fields. To insert 20000 records in one go, use bulk insert (which can vary for different dbms, backend language)

Depending on how you want to use it and what dbms you're using, you can also write the values as a 4 (or 8 if float64) byte * 20000 array into a single column of one row per second.

Do you do the insert for all 20,000 sensor values together or are they all independently written? Also what kind of queries do you need to run on this data once it is stored and how many seconds are you planning to retain? 20000 * 4bytes * 60 6024 *365 would be 2.5 TB

Use a better data model and you don't need 20000 columns. Just 20000 records.

Here's how much space it takes to store 1 minute of the randomly generated per-second readings from 20k sensors with 10% sparsity (they share setseed(), so the random data they save is the exact same):



32 tables625 columns each
numeric[] SQL array
jsonb array
jsonb object
json array
json object
hstore
Entity-Attribute-Value




16MB
11MB
11MB
15MB
14MB
18MB
38MB
55MB



Column names link to documentation, cells link to db<>fiddle demos you can play around with.
In each case you can save space by reducing precision and scale of your readings, e.g. using a numeric(4,2). That results in the array going down in size to 2.5MB and also shows how much of the EAV is just overhead and duplication of the time and sensor signatures, as it only shrinks to 46MB.
Space consumption is only one of the factors, but you can use these as a starting point for further tests.
numeric[]:
create table your_signals(measured_at timestamptz, reading_values numeric[]);
select setseed(.42);--makes this test repeatable
insert into your_signals values
  (now(),(select array_agg(case when .9>random() then random() end) 
          from generate_series(1,2e4)n2) );
select measured_at
  ,reading_values[1] as s1
  ,reading_values[5] as s5
  ,reading_values[9999] as s9999
  ,reading_values[20000] as s20000
from your_signals




measured_at
s1
s5
s9999
s20000




2024-09-07 12:46:21.978572+01
0.362470663311556
0.5754996219675
0.800965200844344
0.906566857051784



jsonb array:
create table your_signals(measured_at timestamptz, reading_values jsonb);
select setseed(.42);--makes this test repeatable
insert into your_signals values
  (now(),(select jsonb_agg(case when .9>random() then random()::numeric(30,15) end)
          from generate_series(1,2e4)n2)
  );
select measured_at
  ,reading_values[0] as s1
  ,reading_values[4] as s5
  ,reading_values[9998] as s9999
  ,reading_values[19999] as s20000
from your_signals




measured_at
s1
s5
s9999
s20000




2024-09-07 12:55:51.234168+01
0.362470663311556
0.575499621967500
0.800965200844344
0.906566857051784



jsonb object:
create table your_signals(measured_at timestamptz, reading_values jsonb);
select setseed(.42);--makes this test repeatable
insert into your_signals values
  (now(),(select jsonb_object_agg('s'||n2,random()::numeric(30,15))filter(where .9>random()) 
          from generate_series(1,2e4)n2) 
  );
select measured_at
  ,reading_values['s1'] as s1
  ,reading_values['s5'] as s5
  ,reading_values['s9999'] as s9999
  ,reading_values['s20000'] as s20000
from your_signals




measured_at
s1
s5
s9999
s20000




2024-09-07 12:59:48.442463+01
0.362470663311556
0.575499621967500
0.800965200844344
0.906566857051784



entity-attribute-value:
create table your_signals(
       measured_at timestamptz
     , source_sensor smallint
     , reading_value numeric);

select setseed(.42);--makes this test repeatable
insert into your_signals 
select now(), n, random() 
from generate_series(1,2e4)n
where .9>random();

--requires a pivot to view sensors in columns
select measured_at
      ,min(reading_value)filter(where source_sensor=1)     as s1
      ,min(reading_value)filter(where source_sensor=5)     as s5
      ,min(reading_value)filter(where source_sensor=9999)  as s9999
      ,min(reading_value)filter(where source_sensor=20000) as s20000
from your_signals
where source_sensor in (1,5,9999,20000)
group by measured_at;




measured_at
s1
s5
s9999
s20000




2024-09-07 12:58:24.030178+01
0.362470663311556
0.5754996219675
0.800965200844344
0.906566857051784




Store all 20000 sensor readings in a json column:
create table sensor (
  time timestamp,
  readings json
);

insert into sensor values (now(), '{"sensor1":1.2, "sensor2":5.3, ..., "sensor20000":2.0}');

Or if you always have all the readings use an array type:
create table sensor (
  time timestamp,
  readings decimal[]
);

insert into sensor values (now(), '{1.2, 5.3, ..., 2.0}');
-- or
insert into sensor values (now(), array[1.2, 5.3, ..., 2.0]);

